# Trying to read JSON from file using Aeson

Tags: json, haskell

Here's my code:

```
import Data.Aeson
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Text
import GHC.Generics
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B

data JSON' = 
    JSON' { 
        foo :: !Text,
        int :: Int
        } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON JSON'
instance ToJSON JSON'

jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "test.json"

getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = B.readFile jsonFile

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- Get JSON data and decode it
    d <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String [JSON'])
    -- If d is Left, the JSON was malformed.
    -- In that case, we report the error.
    -- Otherwise, we perform the operation of
    -- our choice. In this case, just print it.
    case d of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right ps -> print ps
```

`test.json` looks liket his:

```
-- test.json
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "int": 1
}
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Can't make a derived instance of ‘Generic JSON'’:
  You need DeriveGeneric to derive an instance for this class
In the data declaration for ‘JSON'’
```

So far the documentation for `Aeson`, like all documentation on Hackage, is not helpful at all. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. So far it seems like I'm reading a file into a bytestring, transforming it into a "tree" like data structure, and then printing one leaf per node. My code is straight from [this link](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/json)

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

After adding the language extension declaration to the top of the file

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in $: expected [a], encountered Object
```

Not sure what this means.

Comment: Your edited in error is just telling you the decode expected a JSON list, so test.json would look like `[ ... ]` and not `{ ... }`.  The reason your decoder expected a list is your explicit type `[JSON']` instead of just `JSON'`, which would work.

Comment: You ask for `[JSON']`, but provide a json file with a value of type `JSON'`. Perhaps you wanted more square brackets in your json file or fewer in your Haskell file.

Answer (score 3):

you need to put `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}` on the top of your file.

On a side note the documentation of [aeson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.11.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html) says

> ```
> instance ToJSON Person where
>     -- ...
>     toEncoding = genericToEncoding defaultOptions
>
> instance FromJSON Person
>     -- No need to provide a parseJSON implementation.
> ```

I think you probably also forgot the `toEncoding` line in your `ToJSON`.

Comment: This [link](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/starting-with-haskell/libraries-and-frameworks/text-manipulation/json) is able to read the JSON without adding a `toEncoding` function

Comment: Event after adding the extension declaration Im getting an error. Please see edits.

Comment: Every example using `deriving (Generic)` in the Data.Aeson documentation includes this language pragma.  @dopatraman What additional info should be present in the "not helpful at all" documentation to help here?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of the file

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
```

The ability to use `derive (Generic)` is a language extension, and you have to tell GHC that you want this to be turned on.